# Upload Cad files in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, cad

Is it possible to upload cad files to a page created with laravel?

I have seen that in the MimeType class that they offer there is none of the extensions that interest me (STL, OBJ,FBX,DAE,3DS,IGES,STEP,VRML,X3D) and I have tried to use the known mimes (even if do not use the library) and it does not work.

**UPDATE**

To give more information, I'm trying to upload files with the extensions shown above. For example, for the stl type I am testing with *stl* and *application/vnd.ms-pki.stl* which are the ones that appear in the *MimeTypeExtensionGuesser class* of laravel.

The code is as follows:

```
{{Form::file('file_cad_maker', ['class' => 'input-file design-select','id' => 'input-file-cad', 'data-target' => '#input-file-cad-filename', 'data-parsley-max-file-size' => '64', 'data-parsley-allowed-format' => 'application/vnd.ms-pki.stl', 'data-parsley-trigger' => 'change focusout'])}}
```

But the client validation tells me that the file is not the type it should be (when I upload an stl file) and in the server-side, if I print the mime-type of the file it tells me: application/octet-stream, which it's used for files without extension.

Comment: What issue are you facing? What extension/MIME are you trying to upload? Also, please show us the relevant code which is not working for you.

Comment: @waterloomatt done!

Comment: @CristinaV I have the same issue. Can you please post your answer which helps you to solve this.

Comment: @CristinaV please share your solution to this if you got one. Struggling with the same problem:/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this worked for me when uploading autocad file (dwg) files.

```
'file' => 'mimetypes:application/octet-stream'
```